# Unique month/year combination in Django DateTimeField

Tags: django

I've got a `DateTimeField` and like to limit it by month/year, i.e. only one entry per month.

At the moment i use two extra fields (`month` / `year`) combined with `unique_together = ("month", "year")`, but there is definitly a better solution.

```
class someModel(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(unique=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['datetime']
```

Comment: that's really not it, `unique_for_date` will make sure that some field F won't have value X twice for same date. First of all, it will allow different values for F for same date (already breaks OP's requirements) and secondly it goes down to day, which is also not what OP wants

Comment: Martin is right `unique_for_date`, `unique_for_month` or `unique_for_year` won't work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really do it "natively" other than the way you're doing it now since when defining a model you're defining DB-level validation, and say MySQL wouldn't support a DATETIME field with a YEAR+MONTH unique constraint.

What you can do, however, is add your own validator on the field, but this will require additional overhead on saving/updating the model's instances. I've had troubles with datetime/timestamp values myself before and usually the year+month unique constraint solution is by far the most efficient/transparent even if it results in additional storage (but that's the cheapest element, right?)

But if you do decide to go with a single-field unique constraint, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/ - you'll need to add a validator to your field which checks if other objects with that year+month combination exist. Note that this will be very inefficient on a large system as MySQL doesn't support year/month indexes on a DATETIME field either - the value will be passed through a function in a full tablescan and filtered afterwards :(

Answer (score 1):

[Field.unique_for_date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique_for_date) will make instance unique by a certain *field value*.
This will limit by month:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # Set index to field
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # If new instance created
        queryset = SomeModel.objects.filter(
                        datetime__startswith=self.datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-'))

        # If instance changed
        if self.id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.exclude(id=self.id)

        if queryset.exists():
            raise ValidationError('Choose another date')

        super(SomeModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: this is a variation of the field validation I mentioned in my answer. But __startswith is just as inefficient as it turns the datetime value into a string and runs a full table scan. Should work though if you want a slightly "hacky" solution.

Comment: It depends. I've just tested it on my 10k rows table. It's totally ok. Also, afaik field validator takes just it's own value as argument with no id.

Comment: I'm sure it is, but it doesn't change the complexity of the query, it's still O(n), i.e. it will get slower and slower as your table grows from 10k to 100k to 100M until it's unbearable. If you run a query on an index, the complexity is always O(1), no matter the size.

Comment: Yeah, it's bad solution if you had 100m rows table :) Better create extra key. It fits in most cases though.

Comment: yup, like I said - it should work, but it won't scale in theory - up to the OP to decide if that's important to him :)

Comment: There are only 12 month in a year. It totally fits to OP.

Comment: Both answers deserved "accepted answer", this one for usable code, @Martin's answer is clearer on the downsides of both solutions. Thank you!